# Android SQLite Group By Day

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to filter using sqlite query where it returns startdatetime which is in TEXT format.

The query I tried is :-

```
SELECT StartDateTime, GROUP_CONCAT(Remark,',') AS Remarks 
FROM History 
GROUP BY strftime('%D', date(StartDateTime)) 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

This works fine, but it only returns one value which is last value to be exact instead of giving multiple value in list

Does any one know how to do filter by today or month ?

Sample Data :

| ID | startDateTime | remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210311173715854 | test |
| 2 | 20210312100958295 | test2 |
| 3 | 20210312155019778 | test3 |
| 4 | 20210315135920665 | test4 |

Currently when I use above query, it returns 20210315135920665 with all remark without taking account which day its comes from..

What I want to achieve is when I execute query I need to have correct remark on correct datetime...

The result that I am expecting :

| ID | startDateTime | remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210311173715854 | test |
| 2 | 20210312100958295 | test2,test3 |
| 4 | 20210315135920665 | test4 |

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas, I have updated the question, please have a look, thanks

Comment: What is the *correct remark on correct datetime*? Post your expected results in tabular format.

Comment: @forpas, I have updated the question again, when I run query, I want to get only value happens on that day.... I want to have value which returns three startdatetime with their remarks...

Comment: You updated the question without posting your expected results.

Comment: @forpas, Sorry missed,it, I have updated now in better format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates have the format `YYYYMMDDhhmmsssss` so you must group by the first 8 chars:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(StartDateTime, 1, 8) AS date, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Remark) AS Remarks 
FROM History 
GROUP BY date
```

If you want the first datetime of each day:

```
SELECT MIN(StartDateTime) AS firstdatetime, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Remark) AS Remarks 
FROM History 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(StartDateTime, 1, 8)
```